# Whirlpool Duet front-loading washer won't spin

Tags: appliances, washing-machine

I have a Whirlpool Duet front-loading washer.  Sometimes it stops and won't spin then displays code F02.  Usually turning it off for an hour and restarting solves the problem but not tonight.  When I try to restart it, it makes a grumbling sound for a while then gives up and beeps/displays the code.  Previously I opened it up and there were no obvious problems.  I checked the drain pump trap and there was nothing in it.  There isn't much in it so I don't think overloading is the problem.

Comment: Update:  I didn't have time to work on this one myself so I called in an expert.  The impeller on the pump is broken.  New one on order.  It turns out that the washer won't spin when it can't drain.  That's what threw me off.

Answer (score 1):

The pump is bad or you use too much soap. Run a load without soap. If a load of clean clothes makes suds in the washer, you definitely use too much soap.
*The pump can't pump suds* -[shopyourway.com](http://www.shopyourway.com/questions/1067714)

Of course it could be a senor malfunctioning somewhere...

Comment: I don't think it's the soap.  There aren't any suds in it now.  I can't re-run it.  When I try it just grumbles then beeps.